# Adding a semi-transparent cover on an image in a SharePoint View?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I have a custom JSON view in SPO.

It displays an image (the same one each time - don't ask! this is what someone wants!)

I would like the images in the view to show a 50% transparent shadow on hover (similar to [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp))

The CSS is:

```
img:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

How would I add this to my JSON?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "hideSelection": true,
  "height": 100,
  "width": 254,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "img",
        "style": {
          "width": "100%",
          "height": "auto"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "src": "https://....jpg"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "a",
        "attributes": {
          "title": "[$Title]",
          "href": "[$HyperLink]",
          "target": "=if ([$HyperLink] == '', '', '_blank')",
          "role": "heading",
          "aria-level": "3"
        },
        "style": {
          "pointer-events": "=if ([$HyperLink] == '', 'none', 'auto')",
          "text-decoration": "=if ([$HyperLink] == '', 'none', 'auto')",
          "position": "absolute",
          "bottom": "8px",
          "left": "10px",
          "font-size": "16px",
          "color": "White",
          "font-weight": "bold",
          "text-shadow": "1px 1px black"
        },
        "txtContent": "=if ([$HyperLink.desc] == '', '–', toUpperCase([$HyperLink.desc]))"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'ts not possible to add hover-effects as far as I know in JSON-formatting, expect the predefined hover-classes for font and background colors.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to show translucency by generating a card on mouse hover. This is the mouse hover event in SharePoint JSON-Formatting. You can use this method as a backup.

[image]

I used customCardProps and below is your code that I modified:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "hideSelection": true,
  "height": 100,
  "width": 254,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "img",
        "style": {
          "width": "100%",
          "height": "auto"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "src": "https://....jpg"
        }，
        "customCardProps": {
    "openOnEvent": "hover",
    "isBeakVisible": true,
    "formatter": {
        "elmType": "img",
        "attributes": {
            "src":"https://....jpg"
        },
        "style": {
           "opacity": "0.5",
           "height": "100px",
            "width": "245px"
        }
    }
}
      },
      {
        "elmType": "a",
        "attributes": {
          "title": "[$Title]",
          "href": "[$HyperLink]",
          "target": "=if ([$HyperLink] == '', '', '_blank')",
          "role": "heading",
          "aria-level": "3"
        },
        "style": {
          "pointer-events": "=if ([$HyperLink] == '', 'none', 'auto')",
          "text-decoration": "=if ([$HyperLink] == '', 'none', 'auto')",
          "position": "absolute",
          "bottom": "8px",
          "left": "10px",
          "font-size": "16px",
          "color": "White",
          "font-weight": "bold",
          "text-shadow": "1px 1px black"
        },
        "txtContent": "=if ([$HyperLink.desc] == '', '–', toUpperCase([$HyperLink.desc]))"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Reference: [Advanced formatting concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-advanced)

Comment: Thanks for that but I need the image itself to turn semi-transparent. This code puts a new image to the right. I just need the current image to appear semi-transparent.